# Change the parameters a kernel module loads with

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules

When I plug in an SD card in Ubuntu, the module `mmc_block` loads with the value of `mmcblk.perdev_minors` set to `8`. I am pretty sure this is the default value coded into the module. What file might I edit so that when `mmc_block` is ever loaded, `mmcblk.perdev_minors` is set to a different value?

Answer (score 3):

When modules are loaded automatically, this is performed by the [`modprobe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/modprobe.8.html) program. It reads configuration files in [`/etc/modprobe.d`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/modprobe.d.5.html) (older versions only read `/etc/modprobe.conf`). Create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf` and add the line

```
options mmc_block mmcblk.perdev_minors=16
```

Comment: Do you really mean `cocal`?

Comment: @Melab No, but the actual name doesn't matter.